# How do I make use of ng-repeat when using database objects in order to get my search box working?

Tags: php, angularjs, search, laravel-5.3

I'm currently trying to implement a search box in order to filter dossiers, like so:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <form id="search" name="search">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchDossier">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<tr ng-repeat="dossier in dossiers | filter: searchDossier">
    <td>{{ dossier->license_plate }}</td>
</tr>
```

How I fetch the data:

```
public function addLicensePlates(Request $request)
{
    $product_id = $request->input('product_id');
    $license_plates = $request->input('license_plates');

    $plates = explode(',', $license_plates);

    foreach($plates as &$plate) {
        $dossier = new Dossier;
        $dossier->license_plate = trim($plate);
        $dossier->product_id = $product_id;
        $dossier->save();
    }
}
```

Problem is; this won't work. The data that I'm trying to filter (dossier in dossiers) is from my database and not from an Angular object within my controller/view. What would be the correct syntax in my `<tr ng-repeat>` to fetch the data from my `dossiers` table? Or am I supposed to do it in a different way?

Comment: Post your controller, and how you fetch the data.

Comment: @Karim Voilà...